# Ember.js: Cannot access injected object

Tags: ember.js

I created a `Session` object:

```
App.Session = Ember.Object.extend({
  user: null,
  userID: '',
});
```

I injected this object:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
name: 'login',
initialize: function (container, application) {
  App.register('session:main', App.Session, { instantiate: false, singleton: true }); 
  // Add `session` object to route to check user
  App.inject('route', 'session', 'session:main');
  // Add `session` object to controller to visualize in templates
  App.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:main');

  App.register('firebase:main', App.Firebase);
  // Add `session` object to route to check user
  App.inject('route', 'firebase', 'firebase:main');
  // Add `session` object to controller to visualize in templates
  App.inject('controller', 'firebase', 'firebase:main');
  }
});
```

I want to set the `userID` property of `Session` to the ID of the current user as per follow:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  beforeModel: function (transition) {
    var isAuth = false;
    var user = '';
    var store = this.store;
    var _this = this;
    var firebase = new Firebase("https://dynamicslife.firebaseio.com");
    firebase.onAuth(function(authData) {
      if (authData) {
        isAuth = true;
        _this.session.userID = authData.id; //THIS OPERATIONS IS NOT WORKING!!!!!!
      } else {
        isAuth = false;
      }
    });

    // These routes you do not need to be logged in to access.
    var openRoutes = ['home','index','about','stories'];
    var testMode = false;
    if (testMode == false) {
    if (openRoutes.indexOf(transition.targetName) === -1 && isAuth === false) {
      console.log('Please login to access this information');
      this.transitionTo('stories');
    }  
  }
 }
});
```

In the code expression identified above by: `//THIS OPERATIONS IS NOT WORKING!!!!!!`, the `authData.id` contains the proper ID value. However the `_this.session.userID` remains undefined.

I tried to replace `_this.session.userID = authData.id;` with  `_this.session.set('userID', authData.id);` but this gave me the same error.

I think that maybe the Session object is not injected into `Ember.Route.reopen`. If this is the case, how can I get access to the Session object from the the `Ember.Route.reopen`?

Because the `session.userID` is undefined, I get the following error:

```
Error while processing route: statistics.index session is not defined ReferenceError: session is not defined
```

When Ember run this:

```
App.StatisticsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user', session.userID);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it not to instantiate `App.Session`, which means it's the object you want to use, but it's a `class` not an `instance`

```
App.register('session:main', App.Session.create(), { instantiate: false, singleton: true });
```

and `session` exists on `this` in the route, not on the global namespace.

```
App.StatisticsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user', this.session.get('userID'));
  },
});
```

And you should definitely use a setter

```
 _this.session.set('userID', authData.id);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is right on. Question if I may: is `App.register('session:main', App.Session.create(), { instantiate: false, singleton: true });` equivalent to `App.register('session:main', App.Session, { singleton: true });` ?

Comment: Indeed it is, it's even the same as `App.register('session:main', App.Session);` since singleton:true is the default ;)  But I never shy away from explicitly defining things when learning them.